# what are offset pixels?

Tags: graphics, pixel, offset

I am calculating depth of an image. In that calculation I get acquainted with the term offset pixel . But I don't know what is actually a pixel offset.

What are offset pixels?

Comment: pixel offset means you're sampling exactly between texels  and numerical accuracy issues can then introduce a lovely diagonal seam across your image.

Comment: @RahulTripathi..it would be of great help if  you explain a little more...

Comment: https://www.gsi.go.jp/cais/Pixel_Offset_method.html